# How to execute multiple if statements within for loop in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 if statements within 'for loop' but for some reason second if statement is not being executed and I can't figure it out why.

Here's my code:

```
def get_tag_value(instance_id, tag, region):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region)
    ec2_instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)

    for tags in ec2_instance.tags:
        if tag == tags['Key']:
            #return tags['Value']
            tag=tags['Value']
            return tags['Value']
            return None
    return None




    for region in response['Regions']:
        if region['RegionName'] not in regions:
            continue

        try:
            response = ec2.describe_instances()
            start_list = []
            stop_list = []
            tag = ""

            for reservation in response['Reservations']:
                for instance in reservation['Instances']:
                    state=(instance['State']['Name'])

                    auto_start = get_tag_value(instance['InstanceId'], 'auto:start', region['RegionName'])
                    auto_stop = get_tag_value(instance['InstanceId'], 'auto:stop', region['RegionName'])
                    print "start schedule is", auto_start

                    if auto_start:
                        print "Autostart is ", auto_start
                    else:
                        print "no auto start"

                    if auto_stop:
                        print "Autostop is ", auto_stop
                    else:
                        print "no auto stop"
```

Only the result from first if statement is executed. Could someone please give me a hint as to what's wrong here?

Any advice appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: You're unconditionally returning `None` after the first `for` loop

Comment: If I remove both 'None' or leave one the this code works fine when running from script.py but when executed as lambda function then nothing is returned unless I remove 'auto_start=..' and following if statement (or the 'auto_stop')